# HP Business Inkjet 1000 does not work on debian wheezy because of expired ink cardriges

Tags: debian, printing, hplip

HP Business Inkjet 1000 does not work on debian wheezy is ink cardriges are marked as expired, this is a non-feature since cardriges should not degrade on time.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my Business Inkjet and Wheezy and could fix it without having to install anything, the workaround is a little tricky though, it is basically the same that I encountered in the Redmond world a while ago, when I tried to use the Business Inkjet with Win XP.

You need a hex-editor (e.g. ghex) installed that allows you to edit binary files. Then open /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups with it and search for the string "SET TIMESTAMP" (with ghex: Edit -> Find then use the text field on the right side for your search). When you found that, change the string into something different, like "SET TIMESTAMX" and save the file. Now instead of the PCL command that tells your printer the current time you have an illegal PCL command which will be silently ignored.
Voilà, the expired cartridges are brand new again.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be that `hplip 3.10` (installed in debian wheezy) forces the printer to check cardrige expiry date. `hplip 3.13` works fine.

To fix this problem I just had to upgrade `hplip` from testing repository (with all dependencies).